Facebook Graph API /me/accounts Empty But Token Debugger Not Empty
I have a Facebook token that I'm trying to access Pages with but the API is returning an empty array.  That seems like a simple permissions issue but when I debug the token in Facebook's Token Debugger it shows I have permissions to multiple pages.
Is there a way to get the pages to show up in the /me/accounts endpoint? Or is there an endpoint that can get me the granular scopes as listed on the Token Debugger?



Are you sure the token belongs to the user who has admin access to the pages?

They might not.  Do you know if there's an API to retrieve the granular scopes from the token debugger?
